# I want to add to a side bar a Featured Blogs rss feed and looking for suggestions on how to do that in Wordpress

Tags: rss

Blogger.com has a gadget called Blog List that aggregates a list of selected blogs in a RSS feed format.

One way of using it on wordpress is to create a blogger blog that contains only the Blog Links then pulling that RSS into wordpress.

What would like to do in a sidebar widget include the same feeds (right now five blogs) showing the most recent post as they are posted. These would not be my own blogs.

If someone has seen this done and can point me to the page or suggest a plugin that might do what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

The RSSImport plugin can do this, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/ , on a side note I have had better results using SimplePie over MagpieRSS in the settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out on my development setup and it is pretty close to what I want by using the shortcode format